JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory issue in Kotlin Multi Platform project
I have started to develop a kmp project and followed this guidlines. At first everything was good/working as I expected. But somehow I could not open the project on the IOS simulator. Android is still working fine but IOS is not.
I am getting this below error;

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory:
/Users/my-user/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-22.0.1/Contents/Home

I have changed the JAVA_HOME path to another one:

/Users/my-user/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jbr-17.0.9/Contents/Home

but it did not work.
BTW when I run the kdoctor command on the terminal it says; ✓ Your operation system is ready for Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile Development!
I also asked this issue to ChatGPT and it always says these;

set the JAVA_HOME path
check the java path if its' correct
etc.


UPDATE (FIXED)
I have just changed the JAVA_HOME path value to /Users/my-user/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-22.0.1/Contents/Home in Xcode. I followed Xcode > Settings > Locations > Custom Paths.  After that the problem is solved. Thanks @Rondy.

You should be setting it to /Users/my-user/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-22.0.1/ rather than /Contents/Home.
You can also check your installed versions by writing java -version in terminal/powershell.

hey Rondy thanks for your answer, it worked. I have just changed the JAVA_HOME path in xcode (Xcode > Settings > Locations > Custom Path) to
----> /Users/my-user/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-22.0.1/Contents/Home.
